# ENOENT error when renaming uploaded file

Tags: node.js, express, fs

So I have a form which makes a POST request to /fUpload.

This is the route that handles the image upload:

```
router.post('/fUpload', function (req, res){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        // take old path from users file system
        var oldpath = files.fileToUpload.path;
        // rename file
        var temp = Date.now() + files.fileToUpload.name;
        // make new path to save the file to the project directory
        var newpath = '../public/uploads/' + temp;
        // change path of file to new path
        console.log(oldpath);
        console.log(temp);
        console.log(newpath);

        fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.render('testFileUpload', { user : req.user });
        });

    });
});
```

When the form is submitted the Node server crashes and i get this error message:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\FERNAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\upload_0a419ccb6beecbc275c5b2c7a8603a1d' -> 'C:\Users\Fernando Montero\Desktop\public\uploads\1529152383437Android-G-b_46.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I had one to many "." in my path